# input validation operation in shell script with passing first as null and not empty string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, freebsd

```
#! /bin/bash
typeset aflag=""
typeset bflag=""
typeset bval=""
typeset aval=""
typeset curropt=""
typeset -i OPTIND=0       # number of passed args
while getopts a:b: curropt ; do
     case $curropt in
          a)
               aflag=1
               aval="$OPTARG"
               echo "a: $OPTARG"
               ;;

          b)
               bflag=1
               bval="$OPTARG"
               echo "b: $OPTARG"
               ;;

         ?)
               printf "Usage: %s: [-a] [-b value] args\n" $0
               exit 2
               ;;
     esac
done

if [ ! -z "$aflag" ] ; then
     printf 'Option -a "%s" specified\n' "$aval"
fi

if [ ! -z "$bflag" ]; then
     printf 'Option -b "%s" specified\n' "$bval"
fi

shift $(($OPTIND -1))           # clear cmdline
exit 0
```

**Result:**

1. input: bash test.sh -a testA  -b testB
   output:

   ```
     a: testA
     b: testB
     Option -a "testA" specified
     Option -b "testB" specified
   ```
2. input: bash test.sh -a   -b testB

output:

```
    a: -b
    b: testB
    Option -a "-b" specified
```

**Expected 2nd scenario:**

```
 a: 
 b: testB
 Option -a "" specified
 Option -b "testB" specified
```

It is not working as expected in the second scenario.
Can you please have a look at the second scenario? please help me out with possible code changes.

Comment: Just use normal argument parsing instead. Don't use getopts.

Comment: It's doing standard option parsing. The `-a` option takes an argument, so whatever's after it (in this case, "-b") must be that argument. If you want to pass an empty argument to it, use `bash test.sh -a "" -b testB`.

Comment: The usage message is lying. The `-a` option *requires* an argument, since you said `getopts a: ...`. There's no such thing as optional option arguments :-)